# Who do you like (the) better between/out of

Tags: articles

Which one is correct?

1 Who do you like better between Jack and Joshua?

2 Who do you like **the** better between Jack and Joshua?

3 Who do you like better **out of** Jack and Joshua?

4 Who do you like **the** better **out of** Jack and Joshua?

Comment: None of them is very idiomatic. "Who/which do you like better, Jack or Joshua?"

Comment: Isn't it a rule when there are two objects the comparative form should be used with "the"? He is the taller of the two. So, do you think that "the better" is wrong or is it possible to omit "the"?

Comment: The rule doesn't apply to 'liking one better than the other', because _better_ modifies _like_ and doesn't describe the boys. You would say  "Jack is the better singer of the two".